# Github Actions - Concatenating env variables adding redundant space

Tags: github-actions

I set up a dummy example and want to concatenate env variables that will be taken from secrets and encoded to base64 and used further.

I have two secrets `MONGODB_USERNAME`, `MONGODB_PASSWORD`;

Values of secrets are:

```json
{
 "MONGODB_USERNAME": "MONGODB_USERNAME_SECRET_VALUE",
 "MONGODB_PASSWORD": "MONGODB_PASSWORD_SECRET_VALUE"
}
```

content of workflow file:

```yaml
name: Deployment base64-example
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - dev
env:
  CACHE_KEY: node-deps
  MONGODB_DB_NAME: gha-demo
jobs:
  test:
    environment: testing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      MONGODB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.MONGODB_USERNAME }}
      MONGODB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MONGODB_PASSWORD }}
      PORT: 8080
    steps:
      - name: Output information
        run: |
          echo "MONGODB_USERNAME: $MONGODB_USERNAME"
      - name: encode to base64 and  save to file and show file
        run: |
          export "AUTH_TOKEN=$(echo -n "${MONGODB_USERNAME}:${MONGODB_PASSWORD}" | base64)"
          echo $AUTH_TOKEN >> temp
          cat temp
  deploy:
    needs: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Output information
        env:
          PORT: 3000
        run: |        
          echo "MONGODB_DB_NAME: $MONGODB_DB_NAME"
          echo "MONGODB_USERNAME: $MONGODB_USERNAME"
          echo "${{ env.PORT }}"
```

I have code that concatenates variables `MONGODB_USERNAME` and `MONGODB_PASSWORD` encoded them and puts to a `temp` file.

```yaml
        run: |
          export "AUTH_TOKEN=$(echo -n "${MONGODB_USERNAME}:${MONGODB_PASSWORD}" | base64)"
          echo $AUTH_TOKEN >> temp
          cat temp
```

decode works correct

```
echo "TU9OR09EQl9VU0VSTkFNRV9TRUNSRVRfVkFMVUU6TU9OR09EQl9QQVNTV09SRF9TRUNSRVRfVkFM VUU=" | base64 --decode
```

result

```
MONGODB_USERNAME_SECRET_VALUE:MONGODB_PASSWORD_SECRET_VALUE%
```

I don't know why but it adding a space in between when I am doing `cat temp`
[image: github actions]

Why does it add this space and how to fix it?
in the real scenario for example, with jfrog artifactory it can not download private packages because of this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the line wrapping behavior of `base64`. Use the argument `--wrap 0` to `base64` to disable line wrapping. See: [man base64](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64).

Notice the space is included here when using `base64` without arguments:

```bash
alongstring="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog on Stackoverflow"
result=$(echo $alongstring | base64)
echo $result
VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZyBvbiBTdGFja292ZXJm bG93Cg==
```

But if you use `base64 --wrap 0` this doesn't happen:

```bash
result=$(echo $alongstring | base64 --wrap 0)
echo $result
VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZyBvbiBTdGFja292ZXJmbG93Cg==
```